# Spring Security + Container Managed Authentication issue

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I'm using [Spring Security Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) + [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) in order to build a secured web application. The authentication of my users must be handled by my container. I followed those 2 steps in order to achieve that:

1. Secured my whole application in my **web.xml** file:

   ```
   <login-config>
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
   </login-config>
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
           <description>Matches unconstrained pages</description>
           <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
   </security-constraint>
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Secured Areas</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   ```
2. Set up Spring Security with the following class:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvcSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
               .jee().mappableRoles("Admin", "User");
   }
   ```

   }

This configuration seems to be working, for I have to authenticate whenever I try to access any URL within my application context except the static resources (in the /resources/ folder). Then after the login, the correct URL and page are shown (as expected). However, if I try to access another link, I have to log in again. Then, the correct URL and page are shown, and I can access any links without having to log in again. So, my question is: why do I have to log in twice in order not to be requested to log in again?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really an expert on this topic but the way I figured it out was that the session was possibly being created by both the container and spring security. My container authentication is handled by WebLogic. There were a bunch of google results that show how to write a custom filter for preauth but it still never seemed to work right until I changed spring security to be stateless.

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true"
    create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
```